# The behavior of cd command in pipes

Tags: linux, bash, unix

My question is why does cd behave in the way bash behaves when cd is in the beginning or middle of a pipe.

When I give 
cd | ls, it still prints the files in the parent directory, basically in effect, it ignores cd command.

**Why is it not implemented in this way in csh:**
When I give cd | ls, it should cd to home directoy and apply ls on that directory. When control returns to the shell, it should retain the old value of pwd under which the shell is running. 
ie cd in a pipeline should use the changed directory for all the commands to the right of the cd command.

Am I missing some fundamental design principle here?

Answer (score 9):

You are indeed missing a fundamental design principle.

In general, when you start a process it has its own "environment" including all environment variables and current working directory. Any changes that process makes are limited to that process and its children. That's pretty desirable actually, imagine the chaos that could ensue if processes could affect their siblings, or even worse, their parents.

When you have pipeline you have a parent, the shell in which you specified a pipeline and a number of children all "piped" together, each child is has an independent environment.

Once you understand this it's pretty easy to work around things and change directory in the parent.

```
  (cd /etc && ( ls | grep x))
```

here the whole thing is in () so that it runs in a child process, and hence the cd does not affect the current shell, but does affect the pipeline which is running in a (grand-)child process.

Comment: I have one less reputation to mark this as the answer. But your answer makes perfect sense now. Thanks a lot. P.S: I didnt know about paranthesis option. This way, it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: `&&` also makes a pipeline with child processes, but why does it differ from pipe?

Comment: && is not really creating a pipeline, when we use | we connect the output of one child to the input of the next, that's the fundamental "pipe" metaphor. With && we are executing one action followed by another, but **only** if the first one works. In this case that is appropriate, we attempt the cd and only if that worked (the target directory exists) do we attempt the pipelined commands.

Comment: How to direct the output of `cd` while keeping it in the parent process?

Comment: @Timothy Swan not sure what you mean by "it", or which process you mean by parent. The command cd does not produce output if successful, if it fails the error message goes to the stderr of the cd. So cd noplace 2>/tmp/myerrfile would put that error output to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not what pipes are for. They're for directing input/output, not controlling the state of the shell.

If you want the behavior you're describing, use a subshell:

```
( cd ; ls )
```

Comment: Or he could just `ls ~`, couldn't he?

Comment: Or that! It's clearly an example, though, and there are certainly cases where it would make sense to change the directory just for one command.

Comment: Actually, i missed the paranthesis. I was not aware of an option like that. This works perfectly. Thanks.